# How can I disable the password policy complexity and history requirements through prompt?

Tags: windows-7

How can I possibly get to this picture that I've attached through prompt? (the screen with the black background and white writing):

[image: computer settings picture]

I'm trying to reset my whole laptop but this (password policy complexity and history requirements) is getting in the way and I've been told the only way is to disable this. Anyone help me, please thanks! The laptop is a mini Samsung laptop, Windows Enterprise, Model: N150 Plus.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you'd need to change group policy in order to reset your computer. If Group Policy applies and you're running Windows Enterprise, is this your laptop or your employer's laptop? Maybe you should be talking to your employer about this.

Comment: It's a laptop I was given from a mate he just couldn't unlock it. So I was hoping if anyone could help me unlock it.